# Firebase check if username exists using addTextChangedListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello friends I am developing an app and it contains register activity. In this activity app wants username and another information from user. I want app shows dynamically if username exists or not. Moreover, user type username and app says that it is already exists or not via textview without pushing anything, even buttons. So my problem is complicated for me. I think it is basic, so I use for yet I am confused.

When I put martin into edittext which is must contains username the textview show me that "username is already exists." yet when I put another usernames for instance franklin or username that not in database textview show me "What an cool username you picked!" I got it why is like that. For loop works for each username in users and it ends itself when it reached to the last username in the users.

My Firebase Database

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-LNalJeQbFdjPsAKGM8P" : {
      "username" : "trevor"
    },
    "-LNalO92NTntHY_1Xu4T" : {
      "username" : "michael"
    },
    "-LNalS9frQG-E4HlZD0f" : {
      "username" : "franklin"
    },
    "-LNamHiSE6WHdwdTpvFM" : {
      "username" : "lamar"
    },
    "-LNamLampo-FQrhGE0kA" : {
      "username" : "martin"
    }
  }
}
```

My Java Class

```
package com.onurturali.paylass;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Objects;

public class CreateProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button createProfileAction;
    EditText registerUsername, registerFullname, registerAge, registerCity, RegisterAbout;
    TextView isUsernameValidOrNot;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        registerUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
        registerFullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerFullname);
        registerAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerAge);
        registerCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerCity);
        RegisterAbout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerAbout);
        createProfileAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createProfileAction);
        isUsernameValidOrNot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.isUsernameValidOrNot);

        createProfileAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        // When username textbox string changed
        registerUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild(charSequence.toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot id:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String user_id = id.getKey();

                            databaseReference.child("users").child(Objects.requireNonNull(user_id)).child("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.getValue()).toString().equals(registerUsername.getText().toString())){
                                        isUsernameValidOrNot.setText("Kullanıcı adı kullanımda. Başka bir tane demeneye ne dersin?");
                                        isUsernameValidOrNot.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                                    }else{
                                        isUsernameValidOrNot.setText("Kullanıcı adı harika görünüyor. Bence bunu kaçırmamalısın!");
                                        isUsernameValidOrNot.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried below code yet it wasn't work.

```
Boolean isUsernameAlreadyExists;

//...

if(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.getValue()).toString().equals(registerUsername.getText().toString())){
isUsernameValidOrNot.setText("Kullanıcı adı kullanımda. Başka bir tane demeneye ne dersin?");
isUsernameValidOrNot.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
isUsernameAlreadyExists = true;
}else{
    isUsernameValidOrNot.setText("Kullanıcı adı harika görünüyor. Bence bunu kaçırmamalısın!");
isUsernameValidOrNot.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
isUsernameAlreadyExists = false;
}
```

Also I tried boolean query outside method, before ending loop. Not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work probably because of this part here `orderByChild(charSequence.toString())` - this represents a child not a value but you are providing `charSequence.toString()` which is value typed by user. Also why don't you try with `Query` you could simplified your code. For example:

```
Query query =  databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(charSequence.toString()); 
// Note: Above provide your order of children this is just an example

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {...
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! By the way, why edittext gives me error and app is stopped when I clear edittext? try-catch couldn't be the solution.

Comment: No exception. App is directly stopping. I used below codes yet I think it is not the solution. `@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if( registerUsername.getText().length() > 0){
                    registerUsername.setError(null);
                }
            }`